# How to collect some data for IntelliTrace?

Tags: c#, intellitrace

Is it possible to collect data for IntelliTrace only for some code area? E.g., I have some method:

```
public void Foo()
{
  SomeMethod1();//collect
  SomeMethod2();//collect
  SomeMethod3();//not collect
  ...
}
```

In this sample I want to collect data only for SomeMethod1() and SomeMethod2(). Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By creating a custom IntelliTrace event you can collect specific data.  Take a look at this post for details on creating custom events: http://blog.qetza.net/en/2010/03/08/vs-2010-personnalisation-des-vnements-de-lintellitrace/